# taking the difference between two bootstrap date picker dates with different formats

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I use `bootstrap datepicker` in the front end of my web application. the database needs all dates in the format of `dd-mm-yyyy`.  So this is the way I use `datepicker`.

```
  <script>
            $(function() {
                $(".dates").datepicker({ 
                     format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
                     autoclose: true
                });
            });
  </script>
```

I have a new requirement now to check the difference between two date values in months. 
I tried this code:

```
var onBookingDate = new Date(jQuery('#datepick_onBooking').val());
var commencingDate = new Date(jQuery('#commencingDate').val());

var msPerMonth = 1000*60*60*24*30;

    alert(onBookingDate );
    alert(commencingDate );
    alert (Math.floor(commencingDate .getTime() - onBookingDate.getTime())/msPerMonth );
```

in this, it alerts the date in the format of mm-dd-yyyy

i.e : if I select 10-02-2015 (10th of Feb in 2015), it alerts the date as 02 Oct 2015.

How can I change the format of the date getting alerted in to dd-mm-yyyy ? I cannot change the format into mm-dd-yyyy since the database requires the date in the format of dd-mm-yyyy.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to create date objects from invalid string formats for Date constructor.

It is generally easier to use the `getDate()` method in an API for a datepicker than to have to use string values and convert them again.

The API will typically return a date object (jQueryUI, Bootstrap etc).

```
var onBookingDate = jQuery('#datepick_onBooking').datepicker('getDate');
var commencingDate = jQuery('#commencingDate').datepicker('getDate');
```

Reference: **[bootstrap datepicker getDate() docs](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/release/methods.html#getdate)**

Answer (score 0):

Whenever it comes to date handling in javascript, the first pick nowadays should be to include [**moment.js**](http://momentjs.com/) in your project. You can then simply alter the date's format with

```
moment(date here).format('desired format')
```

See the documentation [**here**](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/)

To insert into database, this should be enough:

```
moment(date here).format();
```

moment.js makes it very easy to add or sub dates, you can handle date ranges with ease with [**this plugin**](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/plugins/range/) to moment.js